# is there something wrong with this apache vhost?

Tags: apache-2.2

The ServerName works fine by going via url in a browser and the ServerAlias is going to the default web site. Nothing remarkable in error logs for the site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias www.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /data/sites/domain.com/www/docs

     ErrorLog /data/sites/domain.com/www/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /data/sites/domain.com/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

thx

Here's the default virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks  
         AllowOverride None
         Order deny,allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So it's being served by a different `VirtualHost` block when you request `www.domain.com`?  What's its config look like?

Comment: vhost looks fine to me, which means your problem is somewhere else.  What is your `NameVirtualHost` directive?  Have you checked to make sure that `www.domain.com` doesn't appear in any other sections?

Comment: @shane - the whole config? it's a plain vanilla ubuntu apache2.conf and other ones are working ok. Looking at it more, I think it might be a networking issue. Obviously, domain.com is not the real domain. Just change it because I don't want to put compromising info out there. Definitely not a unix admin.

Comment: let me look into this more as another domain is doing the same thing :-( Fortunately, not in production yet.

Comment: As @DerfK mentioned, I was curious whether `www.domain.com` is configured as the `ServerName` for the default vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `ServerName` is present in your default `VirtualHost`.  This means that Apache will try to figure out the hostname using DNS.  If it's guessing that the correct name is `www.domain.com`, it'll take requests to that address instead of giving them to the vhost with the `ServerAlias` for that name.

Set a junk `ServerName` in that `VirtualHost`, and see if that helps.

Or just `a2dissite default`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CNAME record for the www subdomain in your DNS setup ...  have you checked that?

Comment: I think this is a DNS issue. a cname for www-> root was added